# Copy ASP.Net Membership Provider from .MDF File to SQL Database

Tags: asp.net-membership

I developed an MVC3 app that uses the ASP.Net Membership Provider.  I'm trying to move from using the default ~/App_Data/ASPNETDB.MDF to a database in SQL Server.

To that end, I:

- Created a new database using SSMS
- aspnet_regsql.exe -S .\SQLEXPRESS -A all -d MyNewDbName -E
- Verified that the tables and sprocs were created in MyNewDbName
- Attached ASPNETDB.MDF in SSMS
- Ran the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, with options

  - Copy data from one or more tables or views
  - Select all tables and views / Edit Mappings: Delete rows in existing destination tables
  - **Got Error**: Cannot truncate table dbo.aspnet_Applications because it is being reference by a foreign key constraint.

How can I copy the membership provider database including the existing membership data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard create the database and the new tables for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms183323(v=sql.105).aspx

Either that, or just manually truncate all the records in your destination database first. The Membership, Paths, Roles and Users tables all reference the Applications table, so you'll need to truncate the rows in those tables first before you're able to truncate the Applications table.